# Exclude common rows in tibbles

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for a way to join two tibbles in a a way to leave rows only unique to the first first tibble or unique in both tibbles - simply those one that do not have any matched key.

Let's see example:

```
A <- tibble( A = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))

B <- tibble( A = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

With common `dplyr::join` I am not able to get this:

```
  A
1 d
2 e
```

Is there some way within `dplyr` to overcome it or in general in `tidyverse` to overcome it?

Comment: `dplyr::anti_join(A, B, by = "A")` will return only the rows in A that aren't in B.

Comment: @rpolicastro This is the best answer. Why not put an answer?

Comment: I guess I'll go ahead and add an answer then for posterity, since it addresses their question specifically about using the join functions in dplyr..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use setdiff() function from dplyr library**

```
A <- tibble( A = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
B <- tibble( A = c("a", "b", "c"))
C <- setdiff(A,B)
```

Just to add.
Setdiff(A,B) gives out those elements present in A but not in B.

Comment: There is also a `setdiff()` function in `base` package, so it's better to specify `setdiff()` in your answer is from `dplyr`.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the help. I have updated it now.

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr::anti_join` will keep only the rows that are unique to the tibble/data.frame of the first argument.

```
A <- tibble( A = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
B <- tibble( A = c("a", "b", "c"))

dplyr::anti_join(A, B, by = "A")

#   A    
#   <chr>
# 1 d    
# 2 e
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` possibility (well except the tibble):

```r
A[!A$A %in% B$A,]
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  A    
  <chr>
1 d    
2 e
```